# xpath acting strangely in scrapy

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

Assume I have this code:

```html
<div class="page-header" align="center">
<h4>[<a href='browse?q=@section%200DAY' data-placement='top' rel='tooltip' data-original-title='Browse 0DAY'><strong>FIRST</strong></a>] SECOND-</a><a href=/browse?q=@grp%20GUSH rel='tooltip' data-original-title='Find more from GUSH'><b>THIRD</b></a> <h6>FOUR<br> <br/></h6> Search:
<a href="https://xxx1">xxx</a>,
</h4>
<br/>
</div>
```

I want to filter the text FIRST, SECOND, THIRD and FOUR. How can I do so with with XPATH?

I already tested this, without success:

```
'//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/text()' (for filter SECOND)
'//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/a[@rel=\'tooltip\']/text()' (for filter THIRD)
```

Comment: The HTML you've presented is not well-formed. There is a closing `a` tag without the opening part after the `SECOND` text.

Comment: Very strange `</a>] SECOND-</a>`

Comment: Asking "can you help me with the xpath ?" answer -> "yes" or "no". Asking "How can I do so with XPATH?" might get you a description of how to actually do that. Please re-read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about no distractions, no chit-chat: Thanks should never be part of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/node/text()[1]
```

for filter SECOND and this:

```
//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/a/b/node/text()[1]
```

for filter THIRD

Let me know if it works properly.

Comment: I finally endup with this :

FIRST :
section = ''.join(hxs.xpath('//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/a/strong/text()[1]').extract()).replace(u'\xa0', u'')

SECOND :
rlsname = ''.join(hxs.xpath('//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/text()[2]').extract())
rlsname_cleaned = rlsname.replace("] ","")

THIRD :
grp = ''.join(hxs.xpath('//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/a/b/text()[1]').extract())

FOUR :
date = ''.join(hxs.xpath('//div[@class="page-header"]/h4/h6/text()[1]').extract()).replace(u'\xa0', u'')
date = date[6:25]
date_iso8601 = date[6:-9] + "-" + date[3:-14] + "-" + date[0:-17] + " " + date[-8:]